# How to get list of Css class use in the HTML file?

Tags: html, css

I need list of classes used in an html file. Is there any tool where i can get list of classes in the HTML file?

Comment: Do you need just list of class names, or values also?

Comment: I need class name which use in the HTML like what ever class i apply to control or any other container.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work and it doesn't need jquery:

```
const used = new Set();
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (let { className = '' } of elements) {
    for (let name of className.split(' ')) {
        if (name) {
            used.add(name);
        }
    }
}
console.log(used.values());
```

Comment: had to update it a bit - because it fails with "elements[i].className.split(' ')" - is not a function. here is the updated code - https://jsfiddle.net/dqad4n90/

Comment: updated to fix the es6 solution. Had a reference to an undefined variable seen `seen.add(name)`. It was supposed to be `used.add(name)`. Elegant solution though, really good stuff.

Answer (score 8):

If you've got jQuery on the page, run this code:

```
var classArray = [];
$('*').each(function(){if(this.className!=""){classArray.push(this.className)}})
```

The variable classArray will contain all the classes specified on that HTML page.

Comment: you're going to have duplicates in your result.

Comment: tagnames and IDs are in the list

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript Code will list all the unique classes.

```
var lst=[];
document.querySelectorAll("[class]").forEach( (e)=>{  
e.getAttribute("class").split(" ").forEach( (cls)=>{if( cls.length>0 && lst.indexOf(cls)<0) lst.push(cls);}
);
 });
console.log(lst.sort());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dust Me Selectors.

It's not exactly what you are looking for, it shows a list of UNused selectors. However, I imagine you could use the inverse of the list it provides.

Here is the link: http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Comment: Looks like a good extension, however it's only talking about FF3.5 support! We're now at Firefox "6.0" (4.0 with 2 bugfix releases).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but got here through google so I suspect more people can get here too.

The shortest way, using querySelectorAll and classList (which means, browser support could be an issue: [IE10 for classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#compat-desktop) and [IE8 for querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#compat-desktop) ), and with duplicates, would be:

```
var classes = 0, 
elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    classes = classes + elements[i].classList.length;        
}
```

[I made a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LasagnaAndroid/0dzamcnw/3/) with a fallback for classList (which has the "lowest" browser support) that also counts all elements, all classes and all elements with classes if you're not using `classList`.

I didn't add a unique detection though, might get to it some day.

Comment: Thanks! Nice for a recent solution. Plain vanilla JavaScript --> Doesn't require jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly list classes from **console** (ignoring 'ng-*' angular classes)

```js
(global => {
    // get all elements
    const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    // add only unique classes
    const unique = (list, x) => {
        x != '' && list.indexOf(x) === -1 && x.indexOf('ng-') !== 0 && list.push(x);                    
        return list;
    };
    // trim
    const trim = (x) => x.trim();
    // add to variable
    global.allClasses = [].reduce.call(elements, (acc, e) => e.className.split(' ').map(trim).reduce(unique, acc), []).sort();
    console.log(window.allClasses);
})(window);
```